# Rails 3 halts when started on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xampp, mysql2, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-3

Im developing a project based on CommunityEngine and i installed Rails3 on Ruby1.9.2, Im using mysql2 gem which i think is the problem, i faced many issues and solved them all, when i start the server "rails s" it starts normally but refuses to go on, it seems like working but the it is not it is like halted!

By the way im using XAMPP and using the mysql server came along with it, i tried to install the MySQL Server 5.5.1 but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of problem with Rails and Windows and even more with Rails 3.

I strongly suggest you setup an Ubuntu VM under VirtualBox. I didn't want to do that at first too, but I reached a point I couldn't just keep dealing with windows/rails problems, so I went and setup an Ubuntu and everything works great now =)